# Extending Interrupt Request To Other Processors

Tags: c, linux-kernel, irq

How would one extend an existing interrupt request to other processors? There is already an existing request that was made and enabled on a specific processor. I would like to extend this IRQ, which fires based off a hardware counter, such that there exists an IRQ for each of the processors, and if any of the IRQs are triggered, they are funnelled to the already existing IRQ and its handler. Essentially, I am trying to create an IRQ mux. Has anyone had any experience with this?

A better explanation is that the IRQ is the same across all processors. So, I would like to change an already requested and enabled IRQ (requested, enabled, and handled in a separate .c file) to a percpu IRQ within the new .c file

Comment: Oh wow, this is so 'brave and courageous':)  I'm fairly sure that you could arrange for an interprocessor driver message to force the cores to enter your driver, (somehow).  I'm also fairly sure that I would not touch this with a barge-pole:)  Good luck..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't sound like something you can expect to do in software.

Even if you could, the answer would depend a very great deal on *exactly* what CPU you are using, that CPU's support for multi-processing, any chipset or other supporting circuitry on your board, and so on.

I would expect the general answer to be "you can't do that", though. There are probably exceptions.

Comment: +1 well, all multicore/multiprocessor I've seen have the means for one core to generate a hardware-interrupt of another core.  This is essential to allow preemptive, multitasking kernels to stop a thread running on another core by forcing the core to run an interprocessor driver and then enter the kernel code.  How this might be used, or circumvented, for the OP purpose is beyond me, architecture-dependent as you say, and certainly not anything I would like to approach!